# Logging in as a different user in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want a link that the users can click which supports logging in as a different user and then redirects them back to the same page.The issue is the page currently the user is on is also a layouts page .So the below code will work but take the user to the home page not the layouts page they are currently on which is

```
http://test.net/_layouts/15/EditProfile.aspx
function ChangeLogin()
{
    var url = window.location.host;
    alert(url);
    var loginurl ="http://" + url + '/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true'

      location.href = loginurl;

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

This can be done if you have access to the 2013 server 15 hive. Open 15 hive --> Control Templates-->welcome.ascx . Add the below xml entry:

```
<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="ID_LoginAsDifferentUser"
  Text="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_loginasdifferentuser%>"
  Description="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_loginasdifferentuserdescription%>"
  MenuGroupId="100"
  Sequence="100"
  UseShortId="true"
  />
```

Note: This is a farm level change and will affect all web application and sites on that server.

Method 2:

In the page where you want to add the link to add below tag:

```
<a href="#"  onclick="javascript:LoginAsAnother('/sites/SiteName/_layouts/15/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true', 0)">Sign in as diff user</a>
```

LoginAsAnother() is the method used by SharePoint internally in the method 1(ie OOTB menu under logged in user name).
Here provide the server relative web url before '/_layouts/15/closeConnection.aspx'.

Comment: No I don't want this ..I just want one link on a page content to act as a sign in as a different user.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a link functionality for sign in as different user.